# TextView same height as nearby button

Tags: android, android-layout

Layout for list item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:background="#e2e2e2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make the text view the same height as the button height? AND the text inside the text view is not centered. Any ideas how to center it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these attributes to the `textView`

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/removeButton"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/removeButton"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: This works however the text inside the text-view is not centered. Any idea?

Comment: add the **gravity** attribute to **center** for the textview

Comment: it is, however the content is only centered horizontally not vertically

Comment: **center** attribute will make the content exactly at the center http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/removeButton"
        android:background="#e2e2e2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#e2e2e2"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e2e2e2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/removeButton"
        android:text="textview"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your textview and button inside the `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout 
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
            android:background="#e2e2e2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:layout_gravity="center" // Make the TextView control in the center of it parent Control
android:gravity="center"        // Make text in the center of TextView control
```

to you TextView