# Button and TextView not of same height in different screens

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, textview

I have a button and a textview inside a linear layout.
I set height on both the views to match_parent and launched the app on the following emulators

Nexus 4 (4.7") -- Button and TextView same height

Nexus 5 (4.95")-- Button is smaller than TextView

Nexus 5 (5.96")-- Button is larger than TextView

I have tried both these [android button same height as textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747527/android-button-same-height-as-textview) and
[TextView same height as nearby button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701013/textview-same-height-as-nearby-button)
ones that are closest to my case but none of the solutions work for me.

[image]

PS: For the purists out there, I know the background should not have gradient and should not look like a button. But my bosses demand this design and I can't do anything about it. So please overlook that while responding.

Comment: Try to setting button padding to 0 or using custom background. Both of those will definately solve your issue.

Comment: Button padding doesn't change anything as I have tried it. Background color is not within my control and hence cannot be altered.

Comment: I don't understand this downvoting on Stackoverflow. Someone just comes and downvotes a question without any explanation whatsoever and leaves a genuine question unanswered and unpopular!

Answer (score 0):

Material-design-style buttons, like those provided by built-in AppCompat styles, have custom backgrounds that inset the *visible* background in order to provide space to draw a shadow.

[image]

[image]

The second screenshot is using the developer option "Show layout bounds" to illustrate that, as far as the layout system is concerned, the `Button` and the `TextView` **are** the same height.

Of course, what you care about is that the *user* thinks they're the same height. The easiest way to do this is to add top/bottom margins to the text view (`5dp` works nicely for me; you may have to try other values). This will mean that the two views are **not** the same size, but they will **appear to be**.

[image]

Comment: I tried your approach but it still gives me varied results for different screen sizes. It did work in the Nexus 5 and 6 but Nexus 4 it didn't. The Button grew larger than the text box. And yes, the coordinates on the Android Studio preview for me are shown exactly like how you have put it but still no difference.